# Spring 4 MVC Hibernate Resource not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Was recently following this tutorial : https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-hibernate-tutorial/ , I have followed everything mentioned there but when I go access my app it just shows a 404 with message "The requested resource is not available."

I have already made sure my app compiles and no error were found, I wonder what could be wrong?

also where should i look at for integrating spring 4 with hibernate?

thanks

Comment: did u pasted the view folder in tomcat directory

Comment: @PankajKumar yes I have, still no luck. though i could not find start.bat, so I assumed it's startup.sh / startup.bat

Comment: did u restart the container

Comment: yes i have @PankajKumar